# ORA-01465: invalid hex number while insert data from text area

Tags: html, sql, oracle, jsp

i want insert data from jsp page to oracle database. i use textarea tag for write message.[it s my contact form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtQae.png)

here is my sql code

```
Create Table message(
id  number primary key,
name varchar2(50),
student_id number,
mess varchar2(4000),
reply varchar2(4000));
```

and this is jsp code

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String mess = request.getParameter("mes");
String sid = (String) session.getAttribute("STID");
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "system", "12345");
ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into message values(id_seq.nextval,?,?,?");
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setString(2, sid);
ps.setString(3, mess);
```

when i click button  i get ORA-01465: invalid hex number error. how can i resolve it?

Comment: `insert into message values(id_seq.nextval,?,?,?` is both missing an end parenthesis and the fifth - reply - parameter. You may want to start by fixing that.